# Incorrect filtering the list created via ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, filtering, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array with districts and arrays with cities inside each of them. I've created list via bg-repeat:

```
 <div ng-repeat="district in districts | filter:search:startsWith" class="district">

      <h4 class="district-name">{{ district.district }}</h4>
      <a href="{{ district.link }}">Some info</a>

      <ul class="district-cities">

        <li ng-repeat="city in district.cities">
          {{ city }}
        </li>

      </ul>


    </div>
```

Everything works fine when we are clicking on letter from which the region starts, but when we are clicking on some letter, that isn't first letter of district, but at the same time it is presence in one of the cities, then filtering works incorrect.

Here is working [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MvhXFGGOlLXqapJatfff?p=preview). When you try to click letters `A, B or G` everything is fine, but once you click letter `Z`, then appears two districts that do not start on letter `Z`, but do contain cities which contains letter `Z`.

Sorry for, may be, elementary question, but how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <input id="q" type="text" ng-model="search.district " />
```

and

```
<ul search-list=".letter" model="search.district">
    <li class="letter" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet.letter">{{ letter }}</li>
</ul>
```

it'll mean the filter only acts on the district property of your object. Otherwise angular will look at all properties.

**UPDATE:**

For your second list you'll want to use the search.district as the main search item like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="district in districts | filter:search.district:startsWith" class="district">
```

I've updated the Plunk to include a second list in blue which is searched like this.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your help, but still don't work...On your Plnkr try to click "Z"

Comment: Oops, sorry, I updated the search box functionality but not the letter array. I've edited the answer and updated the Plunkr.

Comment: That works perfect and definitelly is answer on this question! I'll accept it. But at first if you don't mind can I ask you one more question? In case if I have one search input for two lists...One list contains all cities in all districts...and another list contain list of districts with cities(like example above). What I have to do in this case? If I apply your method this would be great for second list, but first one will not work any more...

Comment: I've updated the main answer and Plunk to cater for this.